# fatal error: systemc.h: No such file or directory

Tags: eclipse, systemc

i am trying to build a project in Eclipse, which looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <systemc.h>
int sc_main() 
{
    ... 
}
```

and I gat this error message:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
../src/main.cpp:11:21: fatal error: systemc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

Note: I am new to Eclipse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the SystemC library to your include path.

A detailed post on how to setup SystemC with Eclipse is available here: http://karibe.co/2014/02/setting-up-systemc-and-eclipse-for-c-hardware-simulation/