# How can fix Access Noxim installation Error

Tags: systemc

## Plz Help what is the error when I run the "make"

g++ -g -O3   -I. -I.. -I../src -I/usr/local/systemc-2.3.2/include/systemc-2.2 -c ../src/NoximNoC.cpp
../src/NoximNoC.cpp:14:10: fatal error: systemc.h: No such file or directory
14 | #include <systemc.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile.defs:26: ../src/NoximNoC.o] Error 1

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackOverflow :-)

> systemc.h: No such file or directory

That's the core error here. Maybe that file is indeed not present on your system, or your `make` toolchain can't find it. Please try the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375326/4341322.